# T-SQL to return delimited list of columns with NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For each row in a view, I need returned the ID column for that row, and a delimited-list of all columns in that row that contain NULL.

So:

```
ID | Test1 | Test2 | Test3
5    'a'     'b'     NULL
6    'a'     'b'     'c'
7    NULL    'b'     NULL
```

would return:

```
ID | InvalidColumns
5    Test3
7    Test1,Test3
```

I've seen solutions on SO that can tell you if any columns have NULL, or if a column for all rows in a table have NULLs, but nothing that would list the columns per row.

Thanks!

#### --EDIT--

Besides the ID column, the columns in the table are not known. I need a solution that works with any table/view with an ID column.

Comment: Are the columns fixed? Easiest solution is use a bunch of `CASE` statements but the columns need to be predefined.

Comment: They are not fixed, I need a flexible solution to cover any table/view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the query like this (`STUFF` is required to remove the leading comma
):

```
SELECT ID, 
STUFF(
 CONCAT(CASE WHEN Test1 IS NULL THEN ',Test1' END,
        CASE WHEN Test2 IS NULL THEN ',Test2' END,
        CASE WHEN Test3 IS NULL THEN ',Test3' END
       ), 1, 1, '') as InvalidColumns
FROM table1 WHERE Test1 IS NULL OR Test2 IS NULL OR Test3 IS NULL;
```

If you want to make the query dynamic then use the following query:

```
DECLARE @table AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @cols1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @cols2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @table = 'Table1'

SET @cols1 = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',CASE WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME) + ' IS NULL THEN '',' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ''' END' 
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns c
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' and TABLE_NAME = @table And COLUMN_NAME <> 'Id'
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @cols2 = STUFF((SELECT distinct 'OR ' + QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME) + ' IS NULL ' 
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns c
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' and TABLE_NAME = @table And COLUMN_NAME <> 'Id'
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
            ,1,3,'')

SET @query = N'SELECT ID, STUFF(CONCAT(' + @cols1 + '), 1, 1, '''') as InvalidColumns FROM ' + @table + ' WHERE ' + @cols2

--SELECT @cols1, @cols2, @query
EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

It produces the following result:

```
| ID | INVALIDCOLUMNS |
|----|----------------|
|  5 |          Test3 |
|  7 |    Test1,Test3 |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e4037/26)

Comment: The column names are not known, just the table and that an ID column exists on it

Comment: thanks, I will mark this as answer. However, it would be nice to see a solution that doesn't rely on dynamic SQL.

Comment: I think if the column names are unknown there is no other way. The first query I have provided is doing the job for the known coumns, and it is not a dynamic

Answer (score 0):

This query can help if the columns are fixed.

```
SELECT ID, 
 CONCAT(case when Test1 is null then 'Test1' end,
    case when Test1 is  null and (test2 is null or test3 is null) then ',' end, 
    case when Test2 is null then  'Test2' end,
    case when (Test1 is  null or test2 is null ) and test3 is null then ',' end,    
    case when Test3 is null then  'Test3' end
    )
 as InvalidColumns
FROM table1 WHERE Test1 IS NULL OR Test2 IS NULL OR Test3 IS NULL
```